# How can my Slack-using BotFramework bot ignore messages on all channels except direct?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, slack, slack-api

I know this seems like it's been asked before - but I understand that you can figure out that someone's talking on a Slack channel by inspecting `activity.Conversation.IsGroup` - I'm using this successfully.

This is fine as long as the channel has more than two members! But there's an annoying edge case where newly-created channels, say, or channels just containing two members, have to experience the bot trying to respond to all messages there, until at least 3 members are added to the channel.

Has anyone figured out a handy way to detect this? I inspected the `Activity` JSON for both a message to the app/bot user directly and a message to a channel, but there's no obvious way of being able to distinguish a channel message from a direct-to-bot-user message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember well, there is a difference in Slack in the naming between a channel and a direct messaging: this difference can be seen in the `Conversation.Id` field:

Examples:

- for a channel: il will look like `Bxxxxxxxx:Tyyyyyyyy:Czzzzzzzz`
- for a direct messaging between you and people A: `Bxxxxxxxx:Tyyyyyyyy:Daaaaaaaa`
- for a direct messaging with several people: `Bxxxxxxxx:Tyyyyyyyy:Gbbbbbbbb`

Where:

- `Bxxxxxxxx` is your bot Slack's ID
- `Tyyyyyyyy` is your Slack's workspace ID
- `Czzzzzzzz` is the current channel Slack's ID (visible in the url when using web version of Slack)

You will be able to detect your case by checking the conversation ID

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what I was hoping for. I hadn't seen enough conversation IDs to notice the B,T,C convention (is that a sly crypto reference? :-) )

There might be another, more fragile way too - conversation objects that refer to a Slack channel have a name property - this is missing in conversation objects for direct messaging. An IsNullOrEmpty check could work - but this seems a more dangerous, side-effect-y way to do it. I like the Id convention. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. But even the solution I provided is dangerous, as it is based on Slack's conventions and Bot Connector Service implementation.

Comment: Agreed. But it'll do for the moment. I'll just have to remember this solution when my bot suddenly starts mysteriously replying to every conversation one day, and check the Id format again!